# atoi() always returning zero if false

Tags: c++

I use `atoi()` to convert `argv` to `int`, the problem is when `argv` = zero is a considered parameter in my problem, it will return zero as well.
I tried to loop about all the arguments *except file name for sure*, what to do ?

```
for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
    if (!atoi(argv[i]) && atoi(argv[i]) != zero) {
        std::cout << "invalid" << std::endl;
        return 0;
   }
}
```

I used few cases like == zero, `||` instead of `&&` and so on, same problem always .. I even used `strtol` but same problem as well, I dunno if it's a problem with the algorithm, but I thought about it for a long time.
edit : my arguments are like next : a1.exe add 3 2 1 4 .. I started i = 2 to begin with 3, my arguments are all numbers. the atoi returns 0 if an argument is letter or zero so I want zero to be accepted as a parameter since it's a number. Sorry if I sounded vague or something
reason for editing : people misunderstood my question.

Comment: If you don't want to consider `argv[0]`, then just start iterating at 1.

Comment: Are you wanting `0` to be "ok" or not? What are you actually trying to check for as far as values to determine if it is `invalid`

Comment: What is `zero`? And in `for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)` why `2`? It should be `1`.

Comment: my arguments are like next : a1.exe add 3 2 1 4 .. I started i = 2 to begin with 3, my arguments are all numbers. the atoi returns 0 if an argument is letter or zero so I want zero to be accepted as a parameter since it's a number. Sorry if I sounded vague or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following.
SO your Problem is that you can't determine if your argv[i] contains either a numeric 0 or a letter or other sign.

```
  for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
      for(int x = 0; x < strlen(argv[i])){
        if(!isDigit(argv[i][x])){
          std::cout << "invalid" << std::endl;
          return 0;
        }
      }
    }
```

In this example we get the size of the actual char array that's contained inside of argv[i] than we check every single char if it is a digit.
If it's not we write "invalid" onto the console and return 0;
ofc you probably need to make some exceptions but I think this could be a decent start and help you with your problem

Comment: It actually helped, I added before the 2nd for loop an if condition with !atoi(argv[i]) .. 
The 2nd for loop helped me to accept the zero as a parameter but reject any negative number. So by adding : if(!atoi(argv[i])) at the beginning, it accepted all numbers, and any case suspicious like zero or any letter or gibberish it went to the 2nd for loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert a number and know wether the input string was correct, then you can use the `std::strtol`  family of functions.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

```
const char *val = "123abc";
char *end = nullptr;
int i = std::strtol(val, &end, 10);
if (end != &val[strlen(val)])
    std::cout << "invalid characters in number" << std::endl;
```

`end` points to the first character not converted, so if the whole string is a valid number, it points to the end of it.